# SQL SELECT query on bridge table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-design

I have three tables and one of them is a **bridge table** of the other two tables.

tbl_student (PK is rollno)

*Attributes: rollno, firstname, email, password, year_enrolled*

tbl_sem (PK is semID)

*Attributes: semID, semName*

tbl_stusem (PK is stusemID)

*Attributes: stusemID, rollno, semID*

What would the SELECT query be if the results I'm trying to get is as shown below:

```
rollno      firstname   semID  semName 
B20171010   John        1      Semester 1      
B20171010   John        2      Semester 2 
B20171010   John        3      Semester 3
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select st.rollno, st.firstname, s.semID, s.semName
from tbl_student st
join tbl_stusem sts on st.rollno = sts.rollno
join tbl_sem s on sts.semID = s.semID
```

Comment: this is exactly what im looking for. thank you!

Comment: No worries, please mark as answer if this is the case

Comment: you might consider if a left join is needed

Answer (score 1):

Assuming sql-server

```
   SELECT 
      R.RollNo,
      R.firstname,
      S.semid, 
      S.SemName
    FROM tbl_student  AS R
    INNER JOIN tbl_stusem AS STR
      ON STR.rollno=r.rollno
    INNER JOIN tbl_sem AS S
      ON S.Semid=STR.Semid
```

Comment: this is exactly what im looking for. thank you!

Comment: you might consider if a left join is needed